# Why wont Minecraft debug screen appear

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft 1.16.4 and I needed my coordinates, but the debug screen wouldn't appear. I tried pressing f3 or pressing f3 + fn, but nothing happens.(I play on windows 10).No i dont play on Bedrock.(This only happened after i updated it to 1.16.4)

Comment: "Why won't it won't appear?!" ...That's a tough question to answer, indeed.

Comment: Does pressing F1 or F5 (or Fn+F1 or Fn+F5) do anything?

Comment: no, but thanks.

Comment: @asdfgh then something is seriously broken. F1 toggles GUI, F2 takes screenshots, F5 toggles perspective, F11 toggles windowed/fullscreen... if none works, you have a pretty big problem and you should check if you didn't disable the function keys or toggled them to some sort of multimedia mode or such.

Comment: ok, thanks for the response

Comment: Have you remapped your controls perhaps? If you mapped F3 to something else, or removed the control mapping, that could have caused this problem.

Comment: ok thanks...ill check